# Layout Inflated but not visible

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I am trying to inflate an R.layout inside a LinearLayout with id container. The layout is inflated as i can see in Android Studio's Layout Inspector but not shown in emulator while the app runs.

[image]

The inflation occurs when the button is clicked. The button is inside a cardView. All the cards are generated inside an Adapter. I am posting the getView method of the adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position,View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_draft, parent, false);
    }

    Button show = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final LinearLayout container = convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    final LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            infl.inflate(R.layout.card_text, container,true);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView text = (TextView) ((SwipeStack) parent).getTopView().findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("dsfsfsf");
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

if i move this line

```
                infl.inflate(R.layout.card_text, container,true);
```

outside of the OnClickListener (in the main function's body) it works fine.

I am using this lib
https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack

and this adapter

```
public class SwipeStackAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

private List<Item> mData;
private Context ctx;

public SwipeStackAdapter(Context ctx,List<Item> data) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.card,data);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.mData = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Word getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position,View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_draft, parent, false);
    }

    Button show = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final LinearLayout container = convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    final LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            infl.inflate(R.layout.card_text, container,true);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView text = (TextView) ((SwipeStack) parent).getTopView().findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("dsfsfsf");

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Why is that happened?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the View is inflated and added to the parent ViewGroup (= container) but without a new layout pass the screen remains unchanged. To trigger a layout pass, try `container.invalidate();` after inflating the card text

Comment: I have tried, nothing changed.

Comment: I've set up a small sample app  with your `getView()` code snippet. Unfortunately, everything works, so I am not able to reproduce the problem. If you still need help, please share all the code necessary to reproduce the issue else I can't help you.

Comment: ok, you are right, i posted the lib and the whole adapter!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach new views to existing ones. I don't see you adding your inflated view to another one. If you wanna add the inflated view to a LinearLayout you'll need to do:

```
LinearLayout containerLy = findViewById(R.id.container);
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout_to_be_inflated, null);
//manipulate here your inflated view
containerLy.add(inflatedView);
```

Comment: OP *does* add the inflated View to a ViewGroup (in this case *container*). That's what the `true` is for in `infl.inflate(R.layout.card_text, container,true);`